# How to create dynamic object based on user input or file without schema in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic

I have good command over c++ language.I am interested in creating code which generates the object dynamically for which no schema has already been defined in code.First of all, is it possible to do so in c++? If yes, please anyone would guide me how to do it?

```
For example,

<name>android</name>
<count>5</count>
<version>4.4.4</version>
```

If this is given in file(.xml), the automatic object should be created and I should be able to access it.

> TempObj.name, TempObj.count and TempObj.version etc..

Comment: "good command over c++ language". A bold statement, that. C++ doesn't has schemas, it has types. No, you cannod define a type dynamically. C++ is statically typed.

Comment: You kind of can. Using template provides a nice way to use dynamic types.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do this at runtime in C++.  Types have to be known at compile time in C++.

You can do code generation, i.e. read XML, generate C++, and compile.  Or you can use a slightly different syntax (and much slower performance) to access the methods, basically:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> Object;
Object obj = load("whatever.xml");
assert(obj["name"] == "android");
```

But to do exactly what you've asked will require a different language.  Tons of choices: Python and Lua are two that easily integrate with a C++ application directly, if you want that.

Answer (score 1):

Using a hash table would solve your problem. in C++, the STL (standard template library) provides `std::unordered_map<>`

You should use that to solve your problem.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> hm
```

The API is nice, where you can insert and change elements by using the `[]` operator.

```
hm["name"] = "android"
hm["count"] = "5";
hm["version"] = "4.4.4";
```

If you need dynamic types, you could probably use templates.

You may be wondering why you would use an ordered or an unordered map in C++. With an ordered map, all elements are able to iterated in the order they were inserted, whereas an unordered map the order in which you will access them is random based on the hashed value.